Taking a broad look at stock price
When you look at the maximum timespan of a stock chart, from the year it was issued up to now, some stocks, in fact many of them are at or near their maximums right now. But many people keep buying it. Isn't this very risky? I mean with my very little amount of money and beginner level knowledge to invest, I immediately turn away if a stock is near its max price... But millions of people including experts I am sure, keep buying and selling such stocks everyday.. Moreover on many of them where they show analyist opinions, it writes buy or even strong buy...  I am missing some fundamental point here I know. But what?

Rule 1 of investing:  you can't time the market.   My advice to a person such as yourself:  Regularly invest in a S&P500 fund or ETF and leave it there.

Counter examples:  PFE and LEG are no where near their 52 week highs.


I am missing some fundamental point here I know. But what?

You are missing the point that over history, the stock market has generally trended upward over its entire existence. It may not go up every day, or even every year, but over a long enough period of time the market has always trended up.
It also grows roughly exponentially, meaning it is not a linear growth, but grows at a relatively stable average rate (with plenty of volatility from year to year)  A growth 0f 8% in 1954 when the S&P 500 would to 300 would be a lot smaller now that the S&P 500 index is at 5,000!
It's not just the stock market that grows exponentially. Populations do as well. So do wages on average (I'm talking about actual wages, not the mandated minimum wage). A 5 cent per hour increase in 1960 would seem like a lot, but would minuscule at today's wages.
If you had looked at the price history of Apple in 2005, it was at its all-time high of $1.60 (accounting for splits since then). Now it's at $175. Would you have been crazy to buy Apple in 2005?
The "experts" look at what a stock will do in the future much more than what it's done in the past. They're wrong, often, but if you're right more times than you're wring, you can come out ahead.

And the non-experts don't try to put significant amounts of money on individual stocks; instead we buy index funds, and on average get quite reasonable results riding only that general market trend and "market rate of return "

Ok I understand your answer. And the logic about upward trend if it looked like more or less a straight line (even those I considered risky up to now but anyway).  But what about that uptrend looking like approximately a parabola instead of a straight line for most of these stocks? I mean these stocks are at the uppermost right side of the parabola, and it cannot go on like that forever - it would be almost like an upward vertical line if it continued the same parabola trend. Then I guess it is a trick of how they display the charts

"over history, the stock market has generally trended upward" - How much of an impact do general periods of inflation have on the general rise of markets over a longer period that you mentioned in your answer?

@upstream It is not a parabola - it is exponential growth. On average the market as a whole have averaged somewhere around 8-10% annually depending on how yo measure it. If you continue that growth in perpetuity you'll see an exponential curve. Look at a chart of the market from 1980 to 2000 and a chart from 2000 to 2020 and you'll see roughly the same shape, just at different scales.  I'll add that to my answer.

@iLuvLogix Certainly inflation has an impact because as prices go up, companies make more revenue in the long run, making their stock more valuable. But it's not a direct correlation by any means.

Counterexample: Japan. If you bought into the Nikkei 225 in late 1989, it would have taken you until this year, 2024, to break even.

Remember that inflation affecting cost of manufacturing largely gets passed along to the consumer. Effects on profitability are not simple.

@iLuvLogix In the short run, unexpected inflation (that is, inflation that is higher than expected and thus isn't already priced in) tends to lower stock market returns, and unexpectedly low inflation increases them. Since these cancel out in the long run (if inflation goes on enough, it starts being expected), you're left with just inflation's increase in the nominal value of stock prices. And the nominal increase in stock prices is less than half of the total increase, leaving significant gains even after prices are adjusted for inflation.

A company might well continue to grow and increase its earning in the future. It does not at all follow that the most a company will ever be worth is what it was worth at its past peak.
Look at any graph of the stock market, or of an individual stock's value. Does it tend to stay constant over time, going up a little one year and then back down the next? No. It tends to go up over time. The Dow Jones average is 38,000 today. Five years ago it was 26,500. Ten years ago it was 16,000. I'm an old man, I remember when it was big news that the Dow had cracked the 1,000 mark.
Whatever a stock's past peak, many many stocks will beat that in the coming years.
